# How do you disconnect an idle client in a Spring Webflux application?

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I have a `spring-webflux` application (with Netty under the hood). There is a controller method like this:

```
public Mono<Response> submitBinaryData(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers,
                                       @RequestBody(required = false) Flux<DataBuffer> data) {
    return process(data.timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10)), getContentLength(headers));
}
```

`process()` method is not too interesting, it just writes the binary data to a storage. An important thing is that it knows upfront how much data there is (via `Content-Length` header).

Then, let's imagine that we have a client that got stuck, like this:

```
    byte[] bufferOf1Mb = new byte[1024 * 1024];
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(new URI("http://localhost:8080/")
            .setHeader("Accept", "application/json")
            .setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
            .POST(BodyPublishers.fromPublisher(JdkFlowAdapter.publisherToFlowPublisher(
                    Flux.just(ByteBuffer.wrap(bufferOf1Mb)).concatWith(Flux.never())), 10 * bufferOf1Mb.length))
            .build();
    HttpResponse<String> httpResponse = client.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

This client announces 10Mb of data, but only writes 1Mb and then waits forever.

I'd like such clients to be disconnected after some timeout to avoid wasting resources on clients that have probably broken forever. In the controller method, there is `timeout()` operator that throws a `TimeoutException` if data does not flow for some time. The exception is then caught and processed by an exception handler (not shown): it just returns a `Response` object to the client (as a JSON).

The catch is that even when the timeout happens (it can be seen in the logs), the client does not notice anything. The client is probably waiting for its data to be consumed by the server, and only then will it look at the response. But the input will never be sent. And the server does not close the connection as it wants the client to read the response. So the connection remains open forever.

Debugger also shows that when this happens, `writeWith()` and `setComplete()` are called on the response object.

Is there a way to disconnect such a client? Either using a timeout setting (although `server.netty.` has only one timeout-related setting, `connection-timeout` which is not what's needed here), or programmatically (when it's clear that the client is effectively lost, cut the connection forcibly), or in any other way?

Answer (score 0):

If you use WebClient for http request, you could set a responseTimeout in httpClient when you build the webclient.

```
  @Bean
  public WebClient getWebClient(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {

    ClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(
        HttpClient.create().responseTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
    );

    return webClientBuilder
        .clientConnector(connector)
        .build();

  }
```

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-builder

Comment: Thank you, but this is a client-side setting. What I seek is ability to control this at the server side.